# Custom notification: java.lang.RuntimeException: ..crash on notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to make a custom notification reminder, but there is a crash after this exception in the code.

```
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$9.<init>(NotificationManagerService.java:2800)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.sendMsg(NotificationManagerService.java:2800)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.updateSoundLocked(NotificationManagerService.java:2787)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.enqueueNotificationInternal(NotificationManagerService.java:2055)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.enqueueNotificationWithTag(NotificationManagerService.java:1911)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub.onTransact(INotificationManager.java:103)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2816  4383 E JavaBinder:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 W dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41786700)
10-11 11:13:01.445  2357  2631 E AudioResampler: Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readIntArray(Parcel.java:789)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:339)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:139)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:112)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.screenshot.SaveImageInBackgroundTask.onPostExecute(GlobalScreenshot.java:380)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.systemui.screenshot.SaveImageInBackgroundTask.onPostExecute(GlobalScreenshot.java:126)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-11 11:13:01.445  8979  8979 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code snippet where I am having problem is:

```
private void sendMsg(boolean delayed) {
    if(mNotificationSoundHandler == null) {
        mNotificationSoundHandler = new Handler() { //may be some prob with this 

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, " !!!Handle Message !!!");
                updateSoundLocked();
            }

    };
}
```

Comment: Fix the format of your logCat

Comment: sry for the inconvenience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update your UI outside the UI Thread. You should do something like this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    updateSoundLocked();
});
```

Or even:

```
private void sendMsg(boolean delayed) {
    if(mNotificationSoundHandler == null) {
        mNotificationSoundHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, " !!!Handle Message !!!");
                updateSoundLocked();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Please, refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. the later solution worked for me.. It took the hell out of me .. was working on it since 5 days.. thanks a lot...

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please, don't forget to check the answer as accepted. Thanks.